# Avoid to many SQL query on page reload

Tags: php, sql, performance, web

I have a website page that, on load, fires 10 different queries against a table with 150,000,000 rows.

Normally the page loads in under 2 seconds - but if I refresh too often, it creates a lot of queries, which slow page load time by up to 10 seconds.

How can I avoid firing all of those queries, since it would kill my database?

I have no caching yet. The site works in the following way. I have a table were all URIs are stored. If a user enters a URL I grap the URI out of the called URL and check in the table if the URI is stored. In case the URI is stored in the table I pull the corresponding data from the other tables in a relational database.

An example code from one of the PHP files that pulls the information from the other tables is this

```
<?php
set_time_limit(2);
define('MODX_CORE_PATH', '/path/to/modx/core/');
define('MODX_CONFIG_KEY','config');
require_once MODX_CORE_PATH . 'model/modx/modx.class.php';

// Criteria for foreign Database
$host = 'hostname';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'password';
$dbname = 'database';
$port = 3306;
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;port=$port;charset=$charset";
$xpdo = new xPDO($dsn, $username, $password);

// Catch the URI that is called
$pageURI = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

// Get the language token saved as TV "area" in parent and remove it
if (!isset($modx)) return '';

$top = isset($top) && intval($top) ? $top : 0;
$id= isset($id) && intval($id) ? intval($id) : $modx->resource->get('id');
$topLevel= isset($topLevel) && intval($topLevel) ? intval($topLevel) : 0;
if ($id && $id != $top) {
    $pid = $id;
    $pids = $modx->getParentIds($id);
    if (!$topLevel || count($pids) >= $topLevel) {
        while ($parentIds= $modx->getParentIds($id, 1)) {
            $pid = array_pop($parentIds);
            if ($pid == $top) {
                break;
            }
            $id = $pid;
            $parentIds = $modx->getParentIds($id);
            if ($topLevel && count($parentIds) < $topLevel) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
$parentid = $modx->getObject('modResource', $id);
$area = "/".$parentid->getTVValue('area');
$URL = str_replace($area, '', $pageURI);
$lang= $parentid->getTVValue('lang');

// Issue queries against the foreign database:
$output = '';
$sql = "SELECT epf_application_detail.description FROM epf_application_detail INNER JOIN app_uri ON epf_application_detail.application_id=app_uri.application_id WHERE app_uri.uri = '$URL' AND epf_application_detail.language_code = '$lang'";
foreach ($xpdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    $output .= nl2br($row['description']);
}
return $output;
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: You should have different kind of caching (on pages,sql queries and from language). Do you have something like that already ?

Comment: You could ask the Stack Overflow team. They have some sort of protection for DoS attacks. I found out a couple of minutes ago. The hard way :)

Comment: updated my question with more details

Comment: Have you tried optimizing your query so that it takes a few milliseconds instead of seconds? It seems to me that if your user base ever grows, you'll be in serious trouble.

Comment: Check this link: [How to protect Apache against DOS,DDOS or brute force attacks using mod_evasive and mod_security and mod_qos on Linux Ubuntu 11.04](http://www.mmncs.com/2011/07/how-to-protect-apache-against-dos-ddos-or-brute-force-attacks-using-mod_evasive-and-mod_security-and-mod_qos-on-linux-ubuntu-11-04/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what language you're using, here is some pseudo-code to get you started.

Instead of firing a large query every time your page loads, you could create a separate table called something like "cache". You could run your query and then store the data from the query in that cache table. Then when your page loads, you can query the cache table, which will be much smaller, and won't bog things down when you refresh the page a lot.

Pseudo-Code (which can be done on an interval using a cronjob or something, to keep your cache fresh.):

Run your ten large queries
For each query, add the results to `cache` like so:

```
query_id  |  query_data
----------------------------------------------------
      1   |  {whatever your query data looks like}
```

Then, when your page loads, have each query collect the data from `cache`

It is important to note, that with a cache table, you will need to refresh it often. (either as often as you get more data, or on a set interval, like every 5 minutes or something.)

Comment: Adding a cache is surely a good way to go but since I have more than 30.000.000 pages even "cache-table" could create a big overload. So aditionally I would also need any other protection that makes the resending of queries more difficult, so DDOs protection or simple accept button method on reload

Answer (score 0):

You should do some serverside caching and optimizations.

If I was you I would install Memcached for your database.

I would also consider some static caching like Varnish, this will cache every page as static HTML, With varnish the 2nd (and 3th, 4th,...) request doesn't have to be handled by PHP and MySQL, which will make it load a lot faster when you load it for the 2nd time (within the cache lifetime ofcourse).

Last of all you can help the PHP side handle the data better by installing APC (or an other opcode cache).